# Как изменить название загружаемого файла php

Tags: php, fileupload

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить название загружаемого файла?
Нужно в конце но перед расширением в название файла добавить переменную `$date_file`

```
<?php
$date_file = date("dmYGiv");
$passport = $_FILES['passport_file']['name'];
$passport_name = transliterator_transliterate('Russian-Latin/BGN', $passport);
$uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/users/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['passport_file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $passport_name);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $date_file = date("dmYGiv");
    $passport = $_FILES['passport_file']['name'];
    $passport_name = transliterator_transliterate('Russian-Latin/BGN', $passport);
    $passport_name = addDateToFileName($passport_name);
    $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/users/';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['passport_file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $passport_name);

    function addDateToFileName($file_name){
        $name = substr($file_name, 0, strrpos($file_name, '.'));  
        $extension = substr($file_name, strrpos($file_name, '.'));

        $date_file = date('dmYGiv');

        return $name . $date_file . $extension;
    }
?>
```

Comment: переписал, используйте обновленный вариант)

Comment: `file.data.txt`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6792492e9b688fa8ffb7454c23f6394be1bc38c5

Comment: Прошу прощения. Не увидел strRpos. Зато без расширения не будет работать

Comment: По ТЗ расширение должно быть) Ну кстати ошибки не будет, просто дата в начало имени файла уедет